# Adding External Library to Zephyr

Tags: cmake, zephyr-rtos

Context:

I am trying to add an external library which uses CMake to my Zephyr project. I have explored the [modules documentation](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/guides/modules.html), but this does not seem a good fit as I am unable to modify the upstream library and would like to avoid forking.

To add the library, I am using FetchContent in my Cmake file. This is working successfully and I am able to download and build the files.

Problem:
When linking, I encounter a "Conflicting CPU architectures" error. After inspecting into `compile_commands.json`, I can see the libraries source code is not receiving the same CMAKE_ARGS as the other files, leading to the architecture mismatch.

I am looking for the suggested way of adding external libraries to a zephyr project, without using the module system.

```
FetchContent_Declare(
        my-lib
        GIT_REPOSITORY git@github.com:<HostRepo>/<repoName>.git
        GIT_TAG v0.1.7
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(my-lib)

target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE my-lib)
```

Comment: There is no general answer. It strongly depends on what library you are adding. Or, depends on how do you can/want build the library that you are adding.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing the repo fetching with a toplevel west.yml manifest and including your lib with add_library() or the appropriate cmake function.